# How do i make a widget visible only if the collection has docs in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, visibility

I'm using firebase database and i want to show a certain widget if there was docs only.
i tried this line but it's not the right one.

```
Visibility(
                  visible: controller.doc.isEmpty(),
```

Comment: If you want it to show when the collection is not empty, you need to invert your condition: `visible: !controller.doc.isEmpty(),`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `controller.doc.isEmpty()` does but you want the widget to be visible if the doc is **not** empty. So you have to change it to:

```
Visibility(
  visible: !controller.doc.isEmpty(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code:

```
Visibility(
  visible: controller.doc.isNotEmpty(),
),
```